# AngularJS sorting rows by table header

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, html-table

I have four table headers:

```
$scope.headers = ["Header1", "Header2", "Header3", "Header4"];
```

And I want to be able to sort my table by clicking on the header.

So if my table looks like this

```
H1 | H2 | H3 | H4
A    H    D   etc....
B    G    C
C    F    B
D    E    A
```

and I click on

```
H2
```

my table now looks like this:

```
H1 | H2 | H3 | H4
D    E    A   etc....
C    F    B
B    G    C
A    H    D
```

That is, the content of each column never changes, but by clicking on the header I want to order the columns by, the rows will reorder themselves.

The content of my table is created by a database call done with [Mojolicious](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojolicious) and is returned to the browser with

```
$scope.results = angular.fromJson(data); // This works for me so far
```

The rest of the code I have cobbled together looks something like this:

```
<table class= "table table-striped table-hover">
    <th ng-repeat= "header in headers">
        <a> {{headers[$index]}} </a>
    </th>
    <tr ng-repeat "result in results">
        <td> {{results.h1}} </td>
        <td> {{results.h2}} </td>
        <td> {{results.h3}} </td>
        <td> {{results.h4}} </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How do I order the columns from this point, just by clicking on the header at the top of the table?

Comment: Why don't you do `<a> {{header}} </a>` instead of `<a> {{headers[$index]}} </a>` ?

Comment: Both worked. Idk, it seemed more explicit which header was being thrown down.

Comment: I think the way I wrote it is more "Best practice"

Comment: I agree with you. But whatever the OP decides, it ought to be consistent in both heaers and rows, which it currently is not.

Answer (score 174, accepted):

I think this [working CodePen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fjkcg) that I created will show you exactly how to do what you want.

The template:

```
<section ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <span class="label">Ordered By: {{orderByField}}, Reverse Sort: {{reverseSort}}</span><br><br>
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <a href="#" ng-click="orderByField='firstName'; reverseSort = !reverseSort">
          First Name <span ng-show="orderByField == 'firstName'"><span ng-show="!reverseSort">^</span><span ng-show="reverseSort">v</span></span>
          </a>
        </th>
        <th>
          <a href="#" ng-click="orderByField='lastName'; reverseSort = !reverseSort">
            Last Name <span ng-show="orderByField == 'lastName'"><span ng-show="!reverseSort">^</span><span ng-show="reverseSort">v</span></span>
          </a>
        </th>
        <th>
          <a href="#" ng-click="orderByField='age'; reverseSort = !reverseSort">
          Age <span ng-show="orderByField == 'age'"><span ng-show="!reverseSort">^</span><span ng-show="reverseSort">v</span></span>
          </a>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="emp in data.employees|orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort">
        <td>{{emp.firstName}}</td>
        <td>{{emp.lastName}}</td>
        <td>{{emp.age}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</section>
```

The JavaScript code:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.orderByField = 'firstName';
  $scope.reverseSort = false;

  $scope.data = {
    employees: [{
      firstName: 'John',
      lastName: 'Doe',
      age: 30
    },{
      firstName: 'Frank',
      lastName: 'Burns',
      age: 54
    },{
      firstName: 'Sue',
      lastName: 'Banter',
      age: 21
    }]
  };
});
```

Comment: This is the closest I got it to working. However, I have some hidden headers, they are only unhidden by opening up a modal and selecting a checkbox (the idea being that you shouldn't have to look at columns that aren't relevant to what you need)

The sorting works great for the 4 required columns, but then when I open the modal to select additional headers/columns to display, whenever I next try to do a search, the page reloads..?

Comment: @Zack - Is [this example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CqItg) what you are talking about?

Comment: @Zack - If you feel my answer and comment provided a working solution for your original question please accept it so others looking for the solution will easily find it. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, no it was not your example but some further things in my code that I did not feel the need to write to get my point across. Those issues have since been fixed and your answer accepted :)

Comment: Thanks so much, I've been looking around for a solution that worked for Angular 1.2

Comment: I found this very useful. But, unless I'm mistaken, it utilizes a global reverseSort variable.

Comment: Hi @AdamThomas, I was looking at your code and I was trying to add a minimal change. When I click on another column that was previously selected, I want to sort by default in ascending order. Here is your example with my change. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qVOjvr?editors=1010 The problem is when I want to reorder by a column for which it was already ordered. Nothing happens and no errors are shown.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a fiddle that can help you to do this with AngularJS
http://jsfiddle.net/patxy/D2FsZ/

```
<th ng:repeat="(i,th) in head" ng:class="selectedCls(i)" ng:click="changeSorting(i)">
     {{th}}
</th>
```

Then something like this for your data:

```
<tr ng:repeat="row in body.$orderBy(sort.column, sort.descending)">
    <td>{{row.a}}</td>
    <td>{{row.b}}</td>
    <td>{{row.c}}</td>
</tr>
```

With such functions in your AngularJS controller:

```
scope.sort = {
    column: 'b',
    descending: false
};

scope.selectedCls = function(column) {
    return column == scope.sort.column && 'sort-' + scope.sort.descending;
};

scope.changeSorting = function(column) {
    var sort = scope.sort;
    if (sort.column == column) {
        sort.descending = !sort.descending;
    } else {
        sort.column = column;
        sort.descending = false;
    }
};
```

Comment: this fiddle is using a very old version of angular, so please be aware of that when looking at the code.

Comment: the answer is from 2013, the fiddle is from 2010, the fiddle uses a pre 1.0 version. they are now at 1.2/1.3

Comment: this is my fiddle... the fiddle is from 2013. In 2010 I did not know anything about programming...

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this in AngularJS is to use a Grid.

The advantage with grids is that the row sorting behavior you are looking for is included by default.

The functionality is well encapsulated. You don't need to add ng-click attributes, or use scope variables to maintain state:

```
    <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
    </body>
```

You just add the grid options to your controller:

```
  $scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'myData.employees',
    columnDefs: [{
      field: 'firstName',
      displayName: 'First Name'
    }, {
      field: 'lastName',
      displayName: 'Last Name'
    }, {
      field: 'age',
      displayName: 'Age'
    }]
  };
```

Full working snippet attached:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid', 'ngAnimate']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.myData = {
    employees: [{
      firstName: 'John',
      lastName: 'Doe',
      age: 30
    }, {
      firstName: 'Frank',
      lastName: 'Burns',
      age: 54
    }, {
      firstName: 'Sue',
      lastName: 'Banter',
      age: 21
    }]
  };

  $scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'myData.employees',
    columnDefs: [{
      field: 'firstName',
      displayName: 'First Name'
    }, {
      field: 'lastName',
      displayName: 'Last Name'
    }, {
      field: 'age',
      displayName: 'Age'
    }]
  };
});
```

```css
/*style.css*/
.gridStyle {
    border: 1px solid rgb(212,212,212);
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Custom Plunker</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://angular-ui.github.com/ng-grid/css/ng-grid.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.3/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://angular-ui.github.com/ng-grid/lib/ng-grid.debug.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice alternative. Too bad it's dependent on jQuery.

Comment: The newest ui-grid no longer has a dependence on jQuery. It's still unstable but worth checking out: http://ui-grid.info/

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that sorts by the header. This table is dynamic and changes with the JSON size.

I was able to build a dynamic table off of some other people's examples and documentation. http://jsfiddle.net/lastlink/v7pszemn/1/

```
<tr>
    <th class="{{header}}" ng-repeat="(header, value) in items[0]" ng-click="changeSorting(header)">
    {{header}}
  <i ng-class="selectedCls2(header)"></i>
</tr>

<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in pagedItems[currentPage] | orderBy:sort.sortingOrder:sort.reverse">
        <td ng-repeat="cell in row">
              {{cell}}
       </td>
    </tr>
```

Although the columns are out of order, on my .NET project they are in order.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code without arrows.....i.e by clicking on header it automatically shows ascending and descending order of elements

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/Script.js"></script>
    <style>
        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            font-family: Arial;
        }

        td {
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding: 5px;
        }

        th {
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding: 5px;
            text-align: left;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body ng-app="myModule">
    <div ng-controller="myController">

        <br /><br />
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <a href="#" ng-click="orderByField='name'; reverseSort = !reverseSort">
                            Name
                        </a>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <a href="#" ng-click="orderByField='dateOfBirth'; reverseSort = !reverseSort">
                            Date Of Birth
                        </a>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <a href="#" ng-click="orderByField='gender'; reverseSort = !reverseSort">
                           Gender
                        </a>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <a href="#" ng-click="orderByField='salary'; reverseSort = !reverseSort">
                            Salary
                        </a>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees | orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort">
                    <td>
                        {{ employee.name }}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ employee.dateOfBirth | date:"dd/MM/yyyy" }}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ employee.gender }}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ employee.salary  }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script>
        var app = angular
        .module("myModule", [])
        .controller("myController", function ($scope) {

            var employees = [
                {
                    name: "Ben", dateOfBirth: new Date("November 23, 1980"),
                    gender: "Male", salary: 55000
                },
                {
                    name: "Sara", dateOfBirth: new Date("May 05, 1970"),
                    gender: "Female", salary: 68000
                },
                {
                    name: "Mark", dateOfBirth: new Date("August 15, 1974"),
                    gender: "Male", salary: 57000
                },
                {
                    name: "Pam", dateOfBirth: new Date("October 27, 1979"),
                    gender: "Female", salary: 53000
                },
                {
                    name: "Todd", dateOfBirth: new Date("December 30, 1983"),
                    gender: "Male", salary: 60000
                }
            ];

            $scope.employees = employees;
            $scope.orderByField = 'name';
            $scope.reverseSort = false;

        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a third-party JavaScript library. It will give you that and much more. A good example is datatables (if you are also using jQuery): https://datatables.net

Or just order your bound array in $scope.results when the header is clicked.

Comment: this should still allow me to use the Json object in retrieving the data from the DB? This looks good bu I sort of need it to work with what I ahve so far. It plays nice with Angular JS?

Comment: I don't see why not, searching the web someone already built a directive you can use (though take a look at the code to see if it's written ok): https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/angular/vM2DEMK_NMA

Comment: Alright, I'm going to backup what I have so far and try implenting this, it looks cool enough. Thanks :D

Comment: You can also just order your array in $scope.results , but it's a waste of time to make a good UX for that. Plus I gurantee you will need more advanced stuff later that already exists in datatables :) good luck!

Comment: How can I order my array like you said? I will go back and investigate later, but right no, I just need the columns to be sortable for tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

I'm just getting my feet wet with angular, but I found [this great tutorial.](https://scotch.io/tutorials/sort-and-filter-a-table-using-angular)
Here's a working [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/KRo9X5?p=preview) I put together with credit to Scott Allen and the above tutorial.  Click search to display the sortable table.

For each column header you need to make it clickable - ng-click on a link will work.  This will set the sortName of the column to sort.

```
<th>
     <a href="#" ng-click="sortName='name'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
          <span ng-show="sortName == 'name' && sortReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span>
          <span ng-show="sortName == 'name' && !sortReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top"></span>
           Name
     </a>
</th>
```

Then, in the table body you can pipe in that sortName in the orderBy filter orderBy:sortName:sortReverse

```
<tr ng-repeat="repo in repos | orderBy:sortName:sortReverse | filter:searchRepos">
     <td>{{repo.name}}</td>
     <td class="tag tag-primary">{{repo.stargazers_count | number}}</td>
     <td>{{repo.language}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

First change your controller

```js
    yourModuleName.controller("yourControllerName", function ($scope) {
        var list = [
            { H1:'A', H2:'B', H3:'C', H4:'d' },
            { H1:'E', H2:'B', H3:'F', H4:'G' },
            { H1:'C', H2:'H', H3:'L', H4:'M' },
            { H1:'I', H2:'B', H3:'E', H4:'A' }
        ];

        $scope.list = list;

        $scope.headers = ["Header1", "Header2", "Header3", "Header4"];

        $scope.sortColumn = 'Header1';

        $scope.reverseSort = false;

        $scope.sortData = function (columnIndex) {
            $scope.reverseSort = ($scope.sortColumn == $scope.headers[columnIndex]) ? !$scope.reverseSort : false;

            $scope.sortColumn = $scope.headers[columnIndex];
        }

    });
```

then change code in html side like this

```html
    <th ng-repeat= "header in headers">
            <a ng-click="sortData($index)"> {{headers[$index]}} </a>
    </th>
    <tr ng-repeat "result in results | orderBy : sortColumn : reverseSort">
        <td> {{results.h1}} </td>
        <td> {{results.h2}} </td>
        <td> {{results.h3}} </td>
        <td> {{results.h4}} </td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had found the easiest way to solve this question. If efficient you can use

HTML code: `import angular.min.js`  and the `angular.route.js` library

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>like/dislike</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="likedislikecntrl" bgcolor="#9acd32">
<script src="./modules/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="./modules/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="./likedislikecntrl.js"></script>
</select></h1></p>
<table border="5" align="center">
<thead>
<th>professorname <select ng-model="sort1" style="background-color: 
chartreuse">
<option value="+name" >asc</option>
<option value="-name" >desc</option>
</select></th>
<th >Subject <select ng-model="sort1">
<option value="+subject" >asc</option>
<option value="-subject" >desc</option></select></th>
<th >Gender <select ng-model="sort1">
<option value="+gender">asc</option>
<option value="-gender">desc</option></select></th>
<th >Likes <select ng-model="sort1">
<option value="+likes" >asc</option>
<option value="-likes" >desc</option></select></th>
<th >Dislikes <select ng-model="sort1">
<option value="+dislikes" >asc</option>
<option value="-dislikes">desc</option></select></th>
<th rowspan="2">Like/Dislike</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="sir in sirs | orderBy:sort1|orderBy:sort|limitTo:row" >
<td >{{sir.name}}</td>
<td>{{sir.subject|uppercase}}</td>
<td>{{sir.gender|lowercase}}</td>
<td>{{sir.likes}}</td>
<td>{{sir.dislikes}}</td>
<td><button ng-click="ldfi1(sir)" style="background-color:chartreuse" 
>Like</button></td>
<td><button ng-click="ldfd1(sir)" style="background-
color:chartreuse">Dislike</button></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body> 
</html>
JavaScript Code::likedislikecntrl.js

var app=angular.module("myapp",["ngRoute"]);

app.controller("likedislikecntrl",function ($scope) {
var sirs=[
    {name:"Srinivas",subject:"dmdw",gender:"male",likes:0,dislikes:0},
    {name:"Sharif",subject:"dms",gender:"male",likes:0,dislikes:0},
    {name:"Chaitanya",subject:"daa",gender:"male",likes:0,dislikes:0},
    {name:"Pranav",subject:"wt",gender:"male",likes:0,dislikes:0},
    {name:"Anil Chowdary",subject:"ds",gender:"male",likes:0,dislikes:0},
    {name:"Rajesh",subject:"mp",gender:"male",likes:0,dislikes:0},
    {name:"Deepak",subject:"dld",gender:"male",likes:0,dislikes:0},
    {name:"JP",subject:"mp",gender:"male",likes:0,dislikes:0},
    {name:"NagaDeepthi",subject:"oose",gender:"female",likes:0,dislikes:0},
    {name:"Swathi",subject:"ca",gender:"female",likes:0,dislikes:0},
    {name:"Madavilatha",subject:"cn",gender:"female",likes:0,dislikes:0}



]
$scope.sirs=sirs;
$scope.ldfi1=function (sir) {
    sir.likes++

}
$scope.ldfd1=function (sir) {
   sir.dislikes++

}
$scope.row=8;

})
```