# Unable to do proper sorting on angular ng-repeat

Tags: c#, angularjs, sorting, paging

I am working with angular object .I need sorting and pagination.currently I am working on angular sorting I searched on Google but I am getting sorting like a reverse order of data not getting proper sorting

```
 <th ng-click="orderByField='Number'; reverseSort = !reverseSort">Number
      <span ng-show="orderByField == 'Number'">
      <span ng-show="!reverseSort">
      <i class="fa fa-sort-asc"></i>
      </span><span ng-show="reverseSort">
      <i class="fa fa-sort-desc"></i></span>
      </span>
 </th>
```

and on second side my field is

```
 <tr ng-repeat="ProjectsObj in Projects |orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort>
```

Comment: can you put it into the plunker (plnkr.co)

Answer (score 0):

You can find a working solution here : [AngularJS sorting rows by table header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122942/angular-js-sorting-rows-by-table-header)

But maybe that is what you started from seeing your code.

If that solution is not working, maybe a plunker as Vienna already asked could help?