# How to consider a link as an internal link, but not using routing?

Tags: angularjs

I have a table and wanted to sort table based on a certain column. i have used the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122942/angular-js-sorting-rows-by-table-header). By the way here is the html, i am using.

```
<span class="label">Ordered By: {{orderByField}}, Reverse Sort: {{reverseSort}}</span><br><br>
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <a href="#" ng-click="orderByField='firstName'; reverseSort = !reverseSort">
          First Name <span ng-show="orderByField == 'firstName'"><span ng-show="!reverseSort">^</span><span ng-show="reverseSort">v</span></span>
          </a>
        </th>
 </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="emp in data.employees|orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort">
        <td>{{emp.firstName}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Here is the controller:

```
var app = angular.module('need-for-parking');

app.controller('DriversController', function($scope) {
  $scope.orderByField = 'firstName';
  $scope.reverseSort = false;

  $scope.data = {
    employees: [{
      firstName: 'John',

    },{
      firstName: 'Frank',

    },{
      firstName: 'Sue',

    }]
  };
});
```

Well, using this code i have made a link in the header of my table. The problem is when i click on this link it goes to the main page of application. and i think it is because of this lines in `routing`.

```
.otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/search'
});
```

this means that, it consider this
  `<a href="#" ng-click="orderByField='firstName'; reverseSort = !reverseSort">`

as a internal link and to answer it, it tries to use its routing, which is wrong.

Comment: Can you make fiddle for this? It should work.

Comment: change href="#" to<a href ng-click="orderByField='firstName'; reverseSort = !reverseSort">